Flutter doesn't show correctoy PUSH notifications icon on android
My android mobile app receives push notifications from firebase. Flutter receives them correctly in all application states, but when the app is in the background or closed, the icon that shows the push is the icon defined in AndroidManifest.xml
...
<application
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:allowBackup="false"
     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
     android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
     android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
     android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
     android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait">
...

and not the one defined in the same file for firebase notifications
...
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
     android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_launcher_notification" />
...

I indicate in the respective Flutter code the icon I want to show
...
Future initialize() async {
    final NotificationSettings settings =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission();

    final androidInit =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_stat_ic_launcher_notification');

    final iosInit = IOSInitializationSettings();

    final initSetting = InitializationSettings(
      android: androidInit,
      iOS: iosInit,
    );
...

The icon I use is white with a transparent background, the application icon, however, is in color and with a circular background.
I have tried including the icon in the mipmap and drawable folders, with their respective different folders for different resolutions and the default icon assigned for the application continues to appear.
I expect that push notifications show the icon that I have designated for it.
When my app is in foreground, the icon is the correct, when the app is in background or closed, it shows the icon designated for the app.
